# Swiftui-Picker doesn't show selected value

Tags: core-data, swiftui, picker

Initial position: making two pickers filled from database where the second depends on the first. I followed this [Picker Values from a previous picker - CoreData/SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709462/) example and it works pretty good.
Only one problem: the second picker doesn't show the selected value.

```
    @State var courtSelected = 0
    @State var judgeSelected = 0

HStack{
    Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht \(courtSelected)")){
        ForEach(0..<courts.count){ court in
            Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")")
        }
    }
}
HStack {
    Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
        ForEach(Array(courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges! as! Set<Judges>), id: \.self) { judge in
            Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
```

Only differences:

1. the modification from NSSet to array
2. I had to change @Binding var judgeSelected:Int to @State, because otherwise I have to hand over the judge selected as Parameter beginning from App-Struct.

Printing the $judgeSelected inside the label demonstrates, that this var is never changed.

Comment: put correct `.tag` for your `Text()`

Comment: Yeah! Thank you all for your help and your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Your selection and presentation are differ by type, so add tag:

```
Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht \(courtSelected)")){
    ForEach(0..<courts.count){ court in
        Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")").tag(court)  // << here !!
    }
}
```

Second picker presents objects, so selection should also be an object, like

```
@State var judgeSelected: Judges? = nil
```

Next shows similar case so should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/68815871/12299030

Comment: Hi Asperi, thanks for your help. Unfortunally there‘s no change in behaviour in judge‘s picker, where nothing is displayed.

Comment: Obviously for second picker you have to do the same

Comment: I did ;-), but no changes.

Comment: I think, the problem might be anywhere else (perhaps sitting in front of the computer ;-) ). When I turn the standard picker into radiobuttons, nothing can be selected at all. All judges are displayed as radiobutton with labels but are light grey.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    HStack{
        Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht \(courtSelected)")){
            ForEach(0..<courts.count){ court in
                Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")")
            }
        }
    }
    HStack {
        Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
            // -- here
            ForEach(Array(Set(courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges!)), id: \.self) { judge in  
                Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")")
            }
        }.id(UUID())   // <-- here
    }
}
```

Note also the second `ForEach` with `Set`. PS, do not use forced unwrap, ie. no `!` in your code.

EDIT-1: to avoid the error with `arrayLiteral`, try this:

```
    HStack {
        Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
            if let theJudges = courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges {
                ForEach(Array(Set(theJudges)), id: \.self) { judge in
                    Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }.id(UUID())
    }
```

EDIT-2:

here is my test code that allows the second picker
to depend on the first picker. I used both the `id` marker, and `tag` that
must match the selection type.

Since you don't show your struct code for `court` and `judge`,
I created some example structs for those.
You will have to **adjust the code to cater for your structs**.

Used the `id` of the `Judge` struct in the second picker for the `tag`.
However, there are other ways to have a Int tag, for example using array indices, such as:

```
struct Judge: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var gender: String?
    var name: String?
    var title: String?
}

struct Court: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    var courtsJudges: [Judge]?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var courtSelected = 0
    @State var judgeSelected = 0
    
    @State var courts: [Court] = [
        Court(id: 0, name: "one",
              courtsJudges: [
                Judge(id: 0, gender: "Male", name: "name1", title: "title1"),
                Judge(id: 1, gender: "Male", name: "name2", title: "title2"),
                Judge(id: 2, gender: "Male", name: "name3", title: "title3")
              ]),
        Court(id: 1, name: "two",
              courtsJudges: [
                Judge(id: 3, gender: "Female", name: "name7", title: "title7"),
                Judge(id: 4, gender: "Female", name: "name8", title: "title8"),
                Judge(id: 5, gender: "Female", name: "name9", title: "title9")
              ])
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 77) {
            HStack{
                Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht \(courtSelected)")){
                    ForEach(0..<courts.count) { court in
                        Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")").tag(court)
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
                    if let theJudges = courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges {
                        ForEach(Array(Set(theJudges))) { judge in
                            Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")")
                                .tag(judge.id)
                        }
                    }
                }.id(UUID())
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
 HStack {
     Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
         if let theJudges = courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges, let arr = Array(Set(theJudges)) {
             ForEach(arr.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                 Text("\(arr[index].gender ?? "") \(arr[index].title ?? "") \(arr[index].name ?? "")")
                     .tag(index)
             }
         }
     }.id(UUID())
 }
```

Comment: This throws an error with "Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral:' in call" in line with Array(Set(...

Comment: put your `ForEach(Array(courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges! as! Set<Judges>)` see if it works with that.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible approach to avoid the error you get. Works well for me in my tests.

Comment: updated my answer with the full test code I used. Works well for me, tested on macos 12.5. From your comment, the problem is not "elsewhere (anywhere else)", the `light grey` you see, is because of the missing `tag`.

Comment: My Structs are from a core-data database fetched with ``` @FetchRequest(
  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Courts.name, ascending: true)],
  animation: .default
 )
 private var courts: FetchedResults<Courts>
```Courts and Judges are to many-relations.

Comment: are you saying you cannot find a way to adapt my code to use your structs?

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, but I'm totally new to swift and I try to understand as good as I can.

Answer (score 0):

First: thanks for all the great help so far.

Bringing it all together til now.

The following code creates a picker, but the selection is not shown. Changing to a radioGroup, you can't select anything.

**Here's my edited code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Courts.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var courts: FetchedResults<Courts>
    
    @State var courtSelected = 0
    @State var judgeSelected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht")){
                ForEach(0..<courts.count){ court in
                    Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")").tag(court)
                }
            }
        }
        HStack {
            Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter \(judgeSelected)")){
                ForEach(Array(courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges as! Set<Judges>), id: \.self) { judge in
                    Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")").tag(judge)
                }
            }.id(UUID())
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code above leads to no selection] [image: code above as radioButtons]

The next code still leads to an error

```
HStack {
    Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter: (\(judgeSelected))")){
        if let theJudges = courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges {
            ForEach(Array(Set(theJudges)), id: \.self) { judge in
                Text("\(judge.gender ?? "") \(judge.title ?? "") \(judge.name ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }.id(UUID())
}
```

[image: Code showing error]

I think, the problem has to be anywhere else, because already at the start the picker doesn't show anything and the radios are grey.

Is it, because picker 2 depends on picker 1 and changes when a value in picker 1 is selected?

It's all for macOS on xcode 13.4.1

Comment: The issue is about the type. I linked a question that will give you more detail/answer ion your question. An Int can’t be a Judge. Use the selection of the first pocket as the id for the second picker. It will get recreated when there is a change

Answer (score 0):

I created a complete new project with core data, added two entities (Courts and Judges) with two attributes each (id and name).

Then I only made this view:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Courts.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var courts: FetchedResults<Courts>
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Judges.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var judges: FetchedResults<Judges>
    
    @State var courtSelected = 0
    @State var judgeSelected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if(courts.count > 0) {
            HStack{
                Picker(selection: $courtSelected, label: Text("Gericht")){
                    ForEach(0..<courts.count){ court in
                        Text("\(courts[court].name ?? "Unknown")").tag(court)
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $judgeSelected, label: Text("Richter \(judgeSelected)")){
                    ForEach(Array(courts[courtSelected].courtsJudges as! Set<Judges>), id: \.self) { judge in
                        Text("\(judge.name ?? "")").tag(judge)
                    }
                }.id(UUID())
            }
            HStack {
                Button("neue Gerichte") {
                    addItem()
                    addJudges()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        for id in 0..<3 {
            let newItem = Courts(context: viewContext)
            newItem.id = UUID()
            newItem.name = "Gericht Nr. \(id)"
            
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    private func addJudges() {
        for cd in 0..<courts.count {
            for jd  in 0..<3 {
                let newJudge = Judges(context: viewContext)
                newJudge.id = UUID()
                newJudge.name = "Richter \(jd) am Gericht \(courts[cd].name)"
                newJudge.judgesCourts = courts[cd]
                
                try? viewContext.save()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The result: both pickers are shown, first ist ok, second shows the right judges, but they are not "selectable"

Comment: the tag you use in the second picker, `.tag(judge)` is not correct. It must be of the same type as `judgeSelected`. The tag must match the selection type, in this case `Int` not `judge`. That is why they are not "selectable". Change either the `tag` or the `judgeSelected` so that they have the same type.